# how to use infinite load with bloc in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, bloc, rxdart

I have a problem when using bloc to perform infinite load data, where I use infinite load when retrieving categorical data. The case is when visiting one category, the data in the previous category will enter into another category, this is because the data is not reset when going to another category, the question is how to reset the previous data when moving to another category?

***main.dart***

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiBlocProvider(
      providers: [
        BlocProvider(
            create: (context) =>
                ProductByCategoryBloc()..add(ProductByCategoryEvent())),
      ],
      child: route.GetMaterialApp(
        defaultTransition: route.Transition.cupertino,
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        home: MainPage(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

***bloc.dart***

```
class ProductByCategoryEvent {
  final int idCategory;

  ProductByCategoryEvent({this.idCategory});
}

abstract class ProductByCategoryStateBloc {}

class ProductByCategoryUnitialized extends ProductByCategoryStateBloc {}

class ProductByCategoryLoadedBloc extends ProductByCategoryStateBloc {
  List<Product> products;
  bool max;
  ProductByCategoryLoadedBloc({this.products, this.max});
  ProductByCategoryLoadedBloc copyWith({List<Product> products, bool max}) {
    return ProductByCategoryLoadedBloc(
      products: products ?? this.products,
      max: max ?? this.max,
    );
  }
}

class ProductByCategoryBloc
    extends Bloc<ProductByCategoryEvent, ProductByCategoryStateBloc> {
  ProductByCategoryBloc({ProductByCategoryStateBloc initialState})
      : super(ProductByCategoryUnitialized());

  reloadData() async* {
    ApiReturnValue<List<Product>> products;

    products = await ProductServices.getProductCategory(skip: 0, idCategory: 1);
    yield ProductByCategoryLoadedBloc(products: products.value, max: false);
  }

  @override
  Stream<ProductByCategoryStateBloc> mapEventToState(
      ProductByCategoryEvent event) async* {
    ApiReturnValue<List<Product>> products;
    if (state is ProductByCategoryUnitialized) {
      products =
          await ProductServices.getProductCategory(skip: 0, idCategory: 1);
      yield ProductByCategoryLoadedBloc(products: products.value, max: false);
    } else {
      ProductByCategoryLoadedBloc productLoadedBloc =
          state as ProductByCategoryLoadedBloc;
      products = await ProductServices.getProductCategory(
          skip: productLoadedBloc.products.length,
          idCategory: event.idCategory);
      yield (products.value.isEmpty)
          ? productLoadedBloc.copyWith(max: true)
          : ProductByCategoryLoadedBloc(
              products: productLoadedBloc.products + products.value,
              max: false);
    }
  }
}
```

***ui_kategori.dart***

```
class CategoryProductPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final CategoryProduct category;

  CategoryProductPage({this.category});

  @override
  _CategoryProductPageState createState() => _CategoryProductPageState();
}

class _CategoryProductPageState extends State<CategoryProductPage> {
  int selectedIndex = 0;
  ScrollController controller = ScrollController();
  ProductByCategoryBloc productBloc;

  void onScroll() {
    double maxScroll = controller.position.maxScrollExtent;
    double currentScroll = controller.position.pixels;

    if (currentScroll == maxScroll) {
      productBloc.add(ProductByCategoryEvent(idCategory: widget.category.id));
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    productBloc = BlocProvider.of<ProductByCategoryBloc>(context);
    controller.addListener(onScroll);

    final double itemWidth = (size.width) / 2;
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Container(margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 24), child: Navbar()),
          Container(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - 110,
            child: CustomScrollView(
              controller: controller,
              slivers: <Widget>[
                SliverList(
                  delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(
                    [
                      Container(
                          margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 35, top: 20),
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                          ),
                          child: BlocBuilder<SliderBloc, SliderStateBloc>(
                              builder: (_, state) => (state is SliderLoadedBloc)
                                  ? BannerSection(state.sliders)
                                  : Center(child: loadingIndicator))),
                      Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, bottom: 10, top: 20),
                        child: Text(widget.category.name, style: text17),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                BlocBuilder<ProductByCategoryBloc, ProductByCategoryStateBloc>(
                    builder: (_, state) {
                  if (state is ProductByCategoryUnitialized) {
                    return SliverList(
                      delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(
                        [
                          Center(child: loadingIndicator),
                        ],
                      ),
                    );
                  } else {
                    ProductByCategoryLoadedBloc productLoaded =
                        state as ProductByCategoryLoadedBloc;

                    return SliverGrid(
                      gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                        crossAxisCount: 2,
                        childAspectRatio: (itemWidth + 10) / (200),
                        mainAxisSpacing: 8,
                      ),
                      delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                          (BuildContext context, int index) {
                        if (index < productLoaded.products.length) {
                          return Container(
                              margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                                  left: (index % 2 == 0) ? 10 : 0,
                                  right: (index % 2 == 0) ? 0 : 10),
                              child: GestureDetector(
                                  onTap: () {
                                    Get.to(ProductDetailsPage(
                                      product: productLoaded.products[index],
                                      onBackButtonPressed: () {
                                        Get.back();
                                      },
                                    ));
                                  },
                                  child: ProductCard(
                                      productLoaded.products[index])));
                        } else {
                          return Container(
                              child: Center(child: loadingIndicator));
                        }
                      },
                          childCount: (productLoaded.max)
                              ? productLoaded.products.length
                              : productLoaded.products.length + 1),
                    );
                  }
                }),
                SliverList(
                  delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(
                    [
                      Container(height: 100),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Could you please help me to solve the problem here?